# svg:not(:root) overflow hidden what is it for?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

my `.svg` inside my `next-js` project wont show no matter what, because of:

```
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

what is this for?

changing it to:

```
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

will show the svg icons, but I have another website also using `svg:not(:root) { overflow: hidden; }` and the `svg` icons are showing, I do not see any significant differences of the CSS for these 2x websites, so I am now confused, what is `svg:not(:root)` for?

here is how I use my `svg` in `HTML`:

```
<svg aria-label="check" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; position: relative;" role="presentation">
  <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/test.svg?v=130#check" style="fill: currentcolor;"></use>
</svg>
```

here is how the content of `test.svg` look like:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 750 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <style>
    :root>svg {
      display: none
    }

    :root>svg:target {
      display: block
    }
  </style>

  ...

  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
    <path d="M9 16.17L4.83 12l-1.42 1.41L9 19 21 7l-1.41-1.41z" />
  </svg>

  ...

</svg>
```

Comment: hi, I have updated the question with the `test.svg` file content and how I use the `svg` in html, anything wrong with them?

Answer (score 0):

The first CSS rule you are citing is from the user agent stylesheet (the one the browser automatically applies). It just implements what the [SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/render.html#OverflowAndClipProperties) specification says: the CSS `overflow` property has an initial value of `visible`, but for all `<svg>` elements that are not the root element of a DOM tree, it should be `hidden`. In other words: a clip-path is drawn around the layout box for that element. Everything that is inside that box is shown, everything outside is hidden.

What has this to do with diplaying an icon that clearly sits *inside* the layout box? Nothing. Actually, I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing. For me, the icons remain visible regardless of the `overflow` value.